# Can someone explain this AWK command?

Tags: unix, awk

Im trying to calculate the average of a list of hours, I found an awk command that works pretty well but i want to know how is works.

This is my list of hours:

> ```
> 20:09
> 19:24
> 19:28
> ```

And this is the program

```
awk -F':' '
BEGIN {
    total=0;
}
{
    total+=(($1*3600)+($2*60)+$3);
} 
END {
    a=(total/NR); 
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",(a/3600),((a/60)%60),(a%60)
}' file
```

I understand the first part and how it convert everything into seconds but nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following explanation, based on OP's shown attempts.

```
# Start awk program from here, set field separator as :
awk -F':' '
# The BEGIN block is only executed once, when the script starts
BEGIN{
  # Initialize total
  total=0
}
# Main script executes for each input line
{
  # Convert to seconds: Multiply first field $1 by 3600 and second by 60
  # then add the terms together, and add to total
  total+=(($1*3600)+($2*60)+$3)
}
# The END block executes when we have finished reading all lines
END{
  # Calculate average: divide total by number of lines
  a=(total/NR)
  # Print result, where a/3600 is hours,
  # (a/60)%60 is remainder in minutes, a%60 remainder seconds
  # -- the %02d format specifier takes care to discard any decimals
  printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",(a/3600),((a/60)%60),(a%60)
}
' file   # input file name
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Short answer:** this code computes the average duration of some timing which is located in file `file`

I assume you have a file which looks something like:

```
00:02:30: something1
00:01:14: something2
01:02:04: something3
```

I also assume that the first three values represent a duration in hours minutes and seconds.

What the code does is per line extract the duration and convert it into total seconds and adds it to a value `total`. When all lines are processed, it computes the average duration by dividing it by `NR` which represents the total number of lines processed. It then prints the average value out by converting it back into `hh:mm:ss`

**note:**  the code can be reduced into

```
awk -F':' '{t+=3600*$1 + $2*60 + $3}
           END{t/=NR; printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",t/3600,(t/60)%60),(t%60) }' file
```